# Ruby / Rails Daemon Process.fork Error

Tags: ruby, daemon

So I have a ruby daemon running that uses the 'dameons' gem which every few seconds opens a subprocess using

```
Process.fork { ... do things ... }
```

This has been working absolutely fine for days, until today when all I can get is this error

```
*** below you find the most recent exception thrown, this will be likely (but not certainly) the exception that made the application exit abnormally ***
#<fatal: exception reentered>
*** below you find all exception objects found in memory, some of them may have been thrown in your application, others may just be in memory because they are standard exceptions ***
#<IOError: stream closed>
#<NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory>
#<SystemStackError: stack level too deep>
#<fatal: exception reentered>
```

It happens on every iteration. If I open the subprocess in IRB it works fine. I do not know too much about opening subprocess, does anyone know why this may be happening? Sorry if I have left some info out, its late and I am frustrated. And if I hear another spotify commercial about advance auto parts I am going to lose it.

Comment: It looks like your box is out memory. This is not a good sign, but for now all I can suggest is to restart ruby process. Monitoring who gorges your memory should be helpful as well.

Comment: I have butt laods of memory, and I do not see any of these processes still running via 'ps aux | grep (my named process)'. I don't think this is the answer, at least as far as I can tell

Comment: exactly not the out-of-memory, but out-of-tmp or cache. is it a linux box? show `du`

Comment: Both local osx dev env and EC2 linux box. Can you elaborate what you are looking for from 'du' output?